# Removing Fields from file keeping delimeter intact

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

We have a requirement to remove certain fields inside a delimited file using shell script, but we do not want to loose delimeter. i.e

```
   $cat file1
        col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 
        1234,4567,7890,9876,6754
        abcd,efgh,ijkl,rtyt,cvbn

 now we need to generate different file (say file2) out of file1 with second and fourth column removed with delimeter (,) intact
 i.e
   $cat file2
        col1,,col3,,col5 
        1234,,7890,,6754
        abcd,,ijkl,,cvbn
```

Please suggest what would be easiest and efficient way of achieving this, also as file is having around 300 fields/columns AWK is not working because of its limitation related to number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$2 = $4 = ""}1' FS=, OFS=, file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but **awk '{$2 = $4 = ""}' FS=, OFS=, file1** is not rturning anything where as **awk '{$2 = $4 = ""}1' FS=, OFS=, file1** is throwing syntax error.

Comment: What version of awk?  Did you cut and paste from the answer, or type something and possibly introduce an error?  I'm very curious to know in what implementation of awk this produces a syntax error.

Comment: $ awk '{$2 = $4 = ""}1' FS=, OFS=, file1 awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1 **Another problem is this file is having more then 100 columns so AWK can not be used ?**

Comment: Works in BSD awk version 20070501 (output of `awk --version`) with 5985 columns.  Should work in any posix/sus compliant awk.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; } { $2 = $4 = ""; print }' file1 > file2
```

Which, simply saying:

1. sets input & output field separator to `,` at start,
2. empties fields 2 & 4 for each line, and then prints the line back.

Comment: Thanks for this but this is not working as actual file is having more than 100 columns. and its throwing following error: **awk: trying to access field 103**

Comment: Maybe try `gawk` instead of `awk`.